# Getting the values from all the items in listbox in an arraylist.Win forms

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist, listbox

How can get all the values of the listbox items in an array list of 12 values with one button?

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT PLAYERS.ID, PLAYERS.SURNAME + ', ' + PLAYERS.FIRSTNAME AS PLAYER FROM PLAYERS INNER JOIN TEAMS ON PLAYERS.TEAM_ID = TEAMS.ID WHERE (TEAMS.NAME =oly", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

listBox1.DataSource = dt;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "PLAYER";
listBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want insert into the ArrayList ionly the listbox' valuemembers's you must use a loop

```
ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    myAl.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString());
```

If you want also add the ID you can use `Dictionary` here you can find the mdsn reference [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Dictionary<string,string> dictionary=new Disctionary<string,string>();
for(int i=0; i <dt.Rows.Count;i++)
  dictionary.Add(dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString(),dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString());
```